# Microsoft cloud service/worker role deployment - Method not found?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services

When I deploy a Classic WorkerRole inside a CloudService in Azure i get the following exception. Any insights?

It runs fine locally, but it crashes immediately during deployment.

> 15:05:35 - Instance 0 of role Updater is busy     Details: Starting
>   role...Unhandled Exception: Method not found: 'System.String
>   System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider, System.String,
>   System.Object, System.Object)'.    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationManager.Validate()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationManager.CreateNamespaceManager()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(String
>   connectionString)    at PricingUpdater.WorkerRole.OnStart() in
>   WorkerRole.cs:line 107    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType
>   roleTypeEnum)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.b__0()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had this issue myself and the root cause was the osFamily setting in ServicConfiguration.Cloud.csfg file. Mine was set to 2, which does not support .Net version 4.6.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix#releases

I changed mine to 5 and it all worked again.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to changing the .NET version to 4.6.2 in combination with the updated ServiceBus library 5.0.0.

Changed it back to .NET 4.5.2 and reverted Microsoft.Servicebus NuGet package from 5.0.0 to 3.4.2 and it works fine now.